# Would non-euclidean geometry be possible if Euclid's 5th theorem can be proved using the 4 postulates

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry, incompleteness, noneuclidean-geometry

Elliptic/Hyperbolic geometry maintain the first 4 postulates while modifying the 5th postulate in some way. Now if the 5th postulate of Euclidean geometry was provable from the other 4, wouldn't that mean that that non-euclidean geometry is impossible since they have as axioms the first 4 postulates?

Could this be a proof that 5th postulate of Euclidean geometry cannot be proved using the first 4 and hence must be taken as an axiom (Godel's Incompleteness Theorem, is that you?)

Comment: Yes, it does that mean that, but no, it doesn't mean that in a formal system, so it would not count as a proof.  Plus your reasoning is circular: "If the fifth postulate is provable from the other four, then non-Euclidean geometries are ruled out; since non-Euclidean geometries are ruled out, the fifth postulate is thereby proved."

Comment: What's your question? The 5th postulate is an axiom in Euclidean geometry.

Comment: There were a lot of attempts to prove the 5th postulate

Comment: It's more like - "if 5th postulate was provable from other 4, non-euclidean geometries are ruled out. Since non-euclidean geometry is possible, 5th postulate is not provable from other 4."

Answer (score 1):

This assertion of yours is true:

> Now if the 5th postulate of Euclidean geometry was provable from the
>   other four, wouldn't that mean that that non-euclidean geometry is
>   impossible since they have as axioms the first 4 postulates?

But it's not hard to prove that the 5th postulate *can't* be proved from the other four since there are *models* of both elliptic and hyperbolic geometry *in* Euclidean geometry - for example, the [Poincare disk model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model). That means any contradiction in non-Euclidean geometry must already be present in the first four axioms. (Whether or not those four are self contradictory is another question entirely.)

Answer (score 1):

Elliptic geometry also requires a modification of other axioms, not just the 5th.  So, in your sense, it is impossible.

"In order to achieve a consistent system, however, the basic axioms of neutral geometry must be partially modified."

[Elliptic Geometry at Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticGeometry.html)

Isn't your question rather like asking what would happen if we could prove that $1 = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Non-Euclidean geometries are possible--and arose--because Euclid's fifth postulate seems unprovable but not self-evident. No one has been able to prove it, and the fact that so many have tried seems to argue that it is not self-evident. Hence Lobachevski developed his geometry "in the uncertainty" whether Euclid's fifth postulate is true, and offered a theory of parallels that does not rest on it.